# How to connect to remote linux server in the same network but with different IP address through Python Script

Tags: linux, networking, python-2.7

I am trying to use socket or ssh module to connect to remote linux server in the same network but with different IP address through Python Script to retrive values of files from it.
But I am not able to get extact methods and the code is not working. Can anybody help me with this.

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the raw socket library. Instead, use the [paramiko library](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko) to establish an SSH connection to the second linux server.

Their site contains excellent [examples of usage](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/tree/master/demos).